# how to call a component into anther in reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I cannot import `mystyle.css` file `stylesheet.css` in react kindly anyone tell me to set the  path in react
I want to call `myStyles.css` file into main `stylesheet.js` using this 
import `mystyles` from  `'../components/myStyles.css'`
but I received an error form the browser like this

```
./src/components/Stylesheet.js

Module not found: Can't resolve './src/components/myStyles.css' in 'E:\ReactJS\my-app\src\components'
```

can anybody tell me how to include this file into my `Stylesheet.js` file

Comment: Have you tried import '../components/myStyles.css. Also please make sure path is correct

Answer (score 0):

try: ../ instead of ./

or try placing the file in the public folder and calling from there. I had a similar issue that was helped this way.

Answer (score 0):

you're sure you specified the file path correctly, right ? react js may not automatically select your css file. Make sure you give it the right name.

in the Stylesheet.js file :

```
import '../components/myStyles.css' // sure you're calling it the right way from the right place
```

if the problem is still not resolved, we can examine the files as code snipped.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import css file to the component, you should do it this way:

```
import './myCss.css';
```

instead of

```
import myCss from './myCss.css';
```